# Issue installing Theano in my virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, theano

I'm trying to install Theano in a virtualenv:

```
(dnouri_tut)[xxx@xxx virtualenvs]$ pip install Theano
```

but I get the following error:

```
Installing collected packages: scipy, numpy, Theano
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py", line 249, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
    Complete output from command /home/xxx/virtualenvs/dnouri_tut/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-T3NhHj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/xxx/virtualenvs/dnouri_tut/include/site/python2.6:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py", line 249, in <module>

        setup_package()

      File "/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in setup_package

        from numpy.distutils.core import setup

    ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/home/xxx/virtualenvs/dnouri_tut/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-T3NhHj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/xxx/virtualenvs/dnouri_tut/include/site/python2.6" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JcZ_Qe/scipy
```

I would like not to depend on any system package, so I didn't use the option "--system-site-packages" to create my virtualenv.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Try to reinstall numpy manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by user1615070, I just had to install numpy and scipy in my virtualenv before installing Theano (to not use the system versions).

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, Theano (at least version 0.8) has the [specific command in its documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/0.8.X/install_ubuntu.html#virtualenv). Here it is:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python2.7 theano-env
```